# htaccess: Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard for TLD? (.com, .org...)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

Is there a **wildcard** for **any top level domain** in `.htaccess` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

I want to allow all top level domains (and any subdomain) of `*.example.*`.

So: `example.com`, `example.org`, `any.example.com` ...

Currently it works with:

```
SetEnvIf Origin ^(https?://.+\.example\.com(?::\d{1,5})?|https?://.+\.example\.org(?::\d{1,5})?)$   CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$1
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin  %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e   env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
Header merge  Vary "Origin"
```

Comment: No. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value can only be either just `*` or a single origin literal (with no support for any wildcard characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a partial wildcard in the response.

You need to write code which examines the `Origin` request header, checks that it is acceptable and then echos it back in the response.